# Failed to apply cordova-plugin

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, cordova-plugins

Since about a month ago my Android project with Cordova is giving problems when applying the plugin "com.github.dcendents.android-maven". The error is as follows:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'.
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AndroidMavenPlugin'.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type AndroidMavenPlugin.
         > org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/MavenPomMetaInfoProvider
```

And the gradle code is the next:

```
ext {
    apply from: 'cordova.gradle'
    cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
    cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // The gradle plugin and the maven plugin have to be updated after each version of Android
        // studio comes out
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

group = 'org.apache.cordova'
version = '8.1.0'
```

Another thing that catches my attention is that Android Studio is not able to detect the file 'gradle-wrapper.properties'.

['gradle-wrapper.properties' not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFPEt.png)

The gradle-wrapper.properties must exists, because is in the gradle/wrapper directory, and is write as follows:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

I have tried updating java to different versions, java 1.8, 11, 17, 19.
I've tried upgrading cordova to different versions.
I've tried invalidating cache and restarting Android Studio.
I tried reinstalling Android Studio.
I have tried deleting Android cache files.
I have tried all the related things I have found on the forum.

Nothing works.

This error is making me desperate, please help.

Comment: I no longer work on that project so I don't remember if it was resolved. In any case, the best thing that could have been done with it was to burn it.